# Difference between contains() and matches() for select() in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have decided to spend some time to learn dplyr thoroughly. I have just come across the `select()` function and some of the helper functions that come with it.

By just playing around I have failed to find any difference between the `contains` and `matches` helper functions.

Could someone please provide an example of how they can be used for different purposes?

Thank you,

Comment: `contains` a literal string `matches` regular expression i.e. `matches` can take meta characters like `.` or `$`, `^` used in regex, while `contains` matches a substring literally

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that `matches` can take regex as pattern to match column names and `select` while `contains` does the literal match of substring or full name match.  It is described in the `?select_helpers` as

> contains(): Contains a literal string.
>
> matches(): Matches a regular expression.

Consider a simple example where we want to select columns that have substring 'col'

```
df1 <- data.frame(colnm = 1:5, col1 = 24, col2 = 46)
df1 %>% 
    select(contains("col"))
#  colnm col1 col2
#1     1   24   46
#2     2   24   46
#3     3   24   46
#4     4   24   46
#5     5   24   46
```

Here, it matches the 'col' literally in the column names and select those.  If we change the matching criteria to match 'col' followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) with a regex

```
df1 %>% 
   select(contains("col\\d+"))
#data frame with 0 columns and 5 rows
```

if fails, because it is looking for column name substring `"col\\d+"`

```
df1 %>%
    select(matches("col\\d+")) 
# col1 col2
#1   24   46
#2   24   46
#3   24   46
#4   24   46
#5   24   46
```

whereas `matches` take `regex` and match those patterns